# Accessing the first item in a JSON output using Javascript Fetch API

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to retrieve the latest entry from this [JSON output](https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=MSFT&interval=5min&apikey=demo). The data I am trying to retrieve is the latest entry, an example of which is below (the link above shows the entire json).

```
"Time Series (5min)": {
        "2018-11-21 16:00:00": {
            "1. open": "103.3300",
            "2. high": "103.4300",
            "3. low": "103.0800",
            "4. close": "103.0800",
            "5. volume": "1430557"
        },
```

Obviously I can specify the exact entry by referencing the

`['2018-11-21 16:00:00']`

using square bracket notation and similarly

`['4. close']`

in order to retrieve the data I need, but given that the latest entry is constantly switching date and time, the reference is always changing.

How do I ensure I am always retrieving the latest value?

Comment: The order of iteration in objects is implementation-dependent. So I'm afraid you can't ensure retrieving the latest value by object-related methods.

Answer (score 2):

You can just convert the keys to Date and **sort the keys in descending order**. Then select the first one. Here's a snippet for that:

[This works even if the keys are not ordered when fetched initially]

```js
var obj = {
  "Time Series (5min)": {
    "2018-11-21 16:00:00": {
      "1. open": "103.3300",
      "2. high": "103.4300",
      "3. low": "103.0800",
      "4. close": "103.0800",
      "5. volume": "1430557"
    },
    "2018-11-21 16:00:20": {
      "1. open": "104.3300",
      "2. high": "104.4300",
      "3. low": "104.0800",
      "4. close": "104.0800",
      "5. volume": "1430557"
    },
  }
}

var keys = Object.keys(obj['Time Series (5min)']);

//now sort the dates in descending order
keys.sort(function(a, b) {
    a = new Date(a);
    b = new Date(b);
    return a>b ? -1 : a<b ? 1 : 0;
});

var latestKey = keys[0];
var getVal = obj['Time Series (5min)'][latestKey]; //this is your latest data

console.log(getVal);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the `Time Series (5min)` object in to an array using [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) method. Then access the first index of the array for latest entry

Here's how you get the latest entry using Fetch api

```js
const url = 'https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=MSFT&interval=5min&apikey=demo';

fetch(url)
   .then(response => response.json())
   .then(data => {
      const obj = data['Time Series (5min)'];
      const arr = Object.values(obj);
      const latestEntry = arr[0];
      console.log(latestEntry);
   })
   .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.keys`.It will give an array , then use the index, here 0 to get the first element

```js
let obj = {
  "Time Series (5min)": {
    "2018-11-21 16:00:00": {
      "1. open": "103.3300",
      "2. high": "103.4300",
      "3. low": "103.0800",
      "4. close": "103.0800",
      "5. volume": "1430557"
    },
  }
}
let getKeys = Object.keys(obj['Time Series (5min)'])[0];
let getVal = obj['Time Series (5min)'][getKeys];
console.log(getVal)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't guarantee order in an object, so I don't think this is possible.